# Get recursive group membership of all AD users using Powershell

Tags: powershell, recursion, membership, active-directory-group

I'm trying to make a PS script which would list all Active Directory user group membership (recursive).

I already have working script:

```
import-module activedirectory

$users = get-aduser -Filter {Name -Like "*"} -Searchbase "ou=Users, dc=Domain" | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq 'True' } 

$targetFile = "D:\users.csv"
rm $targetFile
Add-Content $targetFile "User;Group"


foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user

    foreach ($group in $groups)
    {
        $username = $user.samaccountname
        $groupname = $group.name
        $line = "$username;$groupname"
        Add-Content $targetFile $line
    }
}
```

But script doesn't list groups recursively, i.e., if group listed in the output file is part of another group.

Example:

Group1: User

Group2: Group3: User

Script shows only Group1 and 3 but not 2.

What should I add to the first script that it writes group membership recursively?

Comment: You should recursively query `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` for a group, for those group you haven't queried yet.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry I am publishing an answer for a question from 3 years ago but if someone will see it, it can help.
Credit to:
[How to get ALL AD user groups (recursively) with Powershell or other tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552094/how-to-get-all-ad-user-groups-recursively-with-powershell-or-other-tools)

You can use the [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=User,CN=USers,DC=x)"
```

You can use it anywahere that you can use an LDAP filter.

**Example:**

```
$username = 'myUsername'
$dn = (Get-ADUser $username).DistinguishedName
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter ("(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})" -f $dn) | select -expand Name | sort Name
```

**Fix in your script:**

```
import-module activedirectory

$users = get-aduser -Filter {Name -Like "*"} -Searchbase "ou=Users, dc=Domain" | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq 'True' } 

$targetFile = "D:\users.csv"
rm $targetFile
Add-Content $targetFile "User;Group"

foreach ($user in $users)
{
$dn = $user.DistinguishedName
    $groups = Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter ("(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})" -f $dn) | select -expand Name | sort Name

    foreach ($group in $groups)
    {
        $username = $user.samaccountname
        $groupname = $group.name
        $line = "$username;$groupname"
        Add-Content $targetFile $line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you make it a function you can call it recursively. Check this out, I think you'll be pleased with the results:

```
Function Get-ADGroupsRecursive{
Param([String[]]$Groups)
    Begin{
        $Results = @()
    }
    Process{
        ForEach($Group in $Groups){
            $Results+=$Group
            ForEach($Object in (Get-ADGroupMember $Group|?{$_.objectClass -eq "Group"})){
                $Results += Get-ADGroupsRecursive $Object
            }
        }
    }
    End{
        $Results | Select -Unique
    }
}
```

Toss that at the top of your script, and then call it for each user. Something like:

```
import-module activedirectory

$users = get-aduser -Filter {Name -Like "*"} -Searchbase "ou=Users, dc=Domain" -Properties MemberOf | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq 'True' } 

$targetFile = "D:\users.csv"
rm $targetFile
Add-Content $targetFile "User;Group"


foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $Groups = $User.MemberOf
    $Groups += $Groups | %{Get-ADGroupsRecursive $_}
$Groups | %{New-Object PSObject -Property @{User=$User;Group=$_}}|Export-CSV $targetfile -notype -append
}
```

Now, depending on the size of your AD structure that may take quite a while, but it will get you what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the code you provided. But I get error "The term 'Get-ADGroupsRecursive' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Comment: Then you did not put the function that I provided at the top of your script and you tried to run the second part of what I provided either before it or without it entirely.

Comment: You're right, now that part works. But I get error on append part.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question with what you are using and post the error that you are getting at this point.

Comment: Invalid null key at `$Groups | %{New-Object PSObject -Property @{User=$User;$Group=$_}}|Export-CS ..`

Comment: @LamonteCristo Thank you! I'm sure that's why the user got errors. I have corrected the script, and it should work now. Removed a $ from `@{User=$User;$Group=$_}` so that it now reads `@{User=$User;Group=$_}`

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy. Just use [ActiveRoles Management Shell for Active Directory](https://software.dell.com/register/71110/). Cmdlet *Get-QADMemberOf* with parameter *Indirect* is the one you are looking for. Example:

`Get-QADMemberOf john.smith -Indirect`

Comment: `The term 'Get-QADMemberOf' is not recognized`

Answer (score 1):

The Quest object returned already include All Recursive groupes (and first level users) in properties `$_.AllMembers`

```
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
$UsersFirstLevel = ($Members | Get-QADObject -Type Group -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties | Get-QADGroupMember -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties | ?{$_.type -eq 'user'})
$UsersSubGroup = ($Members | Get-QADObject -Type Group -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties | Get-QADGroupMember -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties | ?{$_.type -eq 'group'}).Allmembers | Get-QADObject -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties | ?{$_.type -eq 'user'}

$RecursiveUsers = $UsersFirstLevel
$RecursiveUsers += $UsersSubGroup
$RecursiveUsers = $RecursiveUsers | Sort-Object -Unique
```

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of PowerShell (AD Module) do have *-Recursive* switch. So you can easily use [Get-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps).

Example: *Get-ADGroupMember -Identity My_Group -Recursive*

Comment: This is the wrong way around ;-). `Get-ADGroupMember` (recursively) searches for all group-members of a *group*. 
But the question is: how can select a *user* and find recursively all groups he belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

I have something to add to this that worked for me. Not pretty but got the job done, Feed in a txt file of groups to check. could have it export in a more useful way if lots of groups.

```
$groups = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Export\groups.txt'


function CheckAccount($accountinquestion) {
    if($accountinquestion.objectClass -like 'group'){
        $members = get-adgroupmember $member.name | select name, objectClass, SamAccountName
        foreach($member in $members){
            if($member.objectClass -like 'group'){
                CheckAccount($member.name)
            }
            else{write-host $member.name "," $member.SamAccountName}
        }
    }
}

foreach($group in $groups){
    $members = get-adgroupmember $group | select name, objectClass, SamAccountName
    write-host "--------------------"
    write-host $group
    write-host "--------------------"
    foreach($member in $members){
        if($member.objectClass -like 'group'){
            CheckAccount($member.name)
        }
        else{write-host $member.name "," $member.SamAccountName}
    }
}
```