# Piping output of get-ADUser to Get-ADGroup with an LDAP filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory, pipeline

I'm trying to stitch together two lines of PowerShell, but I just can't figure the syntax. There is [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550868/combine-get-adgroup-and-get-aduser-results) that sounds like it might be what I need,  but it isn't using `-LDAPFilter`.

To generate a list of AD users created in the last 100 days, I use

```
$now = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-100)).Date
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $now} -Searchbase "OU=staff,OU=SMUC_Users,DC=stmarys,DC=ac,DC=ie" |
         Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq 'True' }
```

And this code from ["How to get ALL AD user groups (recursively) with Powershell or other tools?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552094/how-to-get-all-ad-user-groups-recursively-with-powershell-or-other-tools?noredirect=1&lq=1) does the next step, which is to find all the groups that a user is a member of:

```
$username = 'd.trump'
$dn = (Get-ADUser $username).DistinguishedName
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter ("(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})" -f $dn) |
    select -Expand Name
```

but I can't pipe the output of the first into the second to get an overall list.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $now} -Searchbase "OU=staff,OU=SMUC_Users,DC=stmarys,DC=ac,DC=ie" |
    Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq 'True' } |
    Select-Object DistinguishedName |
    Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter ("(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})" -f $_) |
    select -expand Name
```

The error message is:

> Get-ADGroup : The search filter cannot be recognized

I thought the second code snippet extracted the distingushed name and supplied it to the filter, and that is what I have tried to do in the pipeline.

Comment: Untested: `Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter ("..." -f $_)` -> `Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter {"..." -f $_}`. Otherwise: `Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter ("..." -f $_)` -> `%{ Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter ("..." -f $_) }`

Comment: Addendum: you also need `Select-Object DistinguishedName` -> `Select-Object -Expand DistinguishedName`, otherwise you'll have to use `$_.DistinguishedName` later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `ForEach-Object` (alias `%`).

The following code should work:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $now} -SearchBase "OU=staff,OU=SMUC_Users,DC=stmarys,DC=ac,DC=ie" `
| Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq 'True' } `
| %{Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter ("(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})" -f $_.DistinguishedName)} `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

If you want to output both user and group information you can expand the code like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $now} -SearchBase "OU=staff,OU=SMUC_Users,DC=stmarys,DC=ac,DC=ie" `
| Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq 'True' } `
| %{$group = Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter ("(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})" -f $_.DistinguishedName);Write-Output $_.UserPrincipalName $group.Name}
```

Comment: How can I get the username alongside the group name in the output?! I've just realised that using a loop isn't much use if it only lists groups and not the associated username

Comment: See my edit. Also it's possible to format the output differently of course.